# Undefined variable error in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

So, I am not sure why I am getting the following error when loading my view :

> Undefined variable: document(View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\learn-laravel\resources\views\edit-record.blade.php)

My controller action is looking like this :

```
public function edit($id)
    {

        $document= Document::where('id',$id)->get();
        //dd($document);

        return view('edit-record')->with('$document',$document);
    }
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="input-group inptit form-group">
        {{Form::text('title',$document->name,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter document title...'])}}
    </div>
@endsection
```

Can anyone explain why am I getting this error? I am clearly passing the record to the view? When I debug with `dd()` I can see the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.

Change this:

```
with('$document',$document);
```

to this :

```
with('document',$document);
```

Cheers

Comment: Oh well...I guess I am done for today. Thanks.

Comment: another way is compact('document')